# Intellij won't stop on breakpoints if i build and run using gradle

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I have composite gradle project that looks like this:

rootProject (basically just wrapper for other projects)
-project1
--build.gradle
--settings.gradle
-project2
--build.gradle
--settings.gradle
...
-build.gradle
-settings.gradle

in outer settings.gradle file i connect all my projects so they compile with gradle's includeBuild method.  Outer build.gradle file is basically empty.

So my problem is following. If i run tests in debug mode in project1/project2... it won't stop on breakpoints if my gradle settings (in intellij) are configured to build and run/ run tests using Gradle. If i use Intellij it is working fine. Also running tests with code coverage doesn't work too, tests are being run but they dont result in code coverage info. And yes, this problem occurs only with tests, if i create breakpoint in main function it is working properly.

I use gradle 7.2 and java 17.

Edit: i created simple gradle project, funny enough i can't debug main here too. (it won't stop on breakpoint)

https://github.com/andriiromaniuk/gradleTest

[build and run settings that needs to be changed so tests are debugable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v49v0.png)

Comment: Java 17 support start with gradle 7.3 , for full information about [compatibility](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html).

Comment: nope, did not work. Changed gradle in gradle/wrapper to 7.3 and it still does not stop on breakpoint. Would really like if you tried my project though. And yeah, it is fresh Intellij install.

Comment: I have the same problem, no breakpoints hit in composite build unit tests